# Packing fraction of atoms in a HCP structure

Tags: condensed-matter

I am looking to find the ratio of atomic sphere to unit cell volume in  a HCP (hexagonal close packing) arrangement.  Some sources I have say it is 0.74

My unit cell structure is that shown below. I labeled the height between the two hexagonal planes by $h$ and the length of the equilateral triangles comprising the hexagon by $2r$. If we then consider a 1/6 of this structure in the obvious way and orient it suitably so that one of the sides of the lower triangles coincides with the x axis say, then the volume of 1/6 of this structure is $$V = 2 \int_0^{r} \int_0^{\sqrt{3}x} \int_0^h dx dy dz = \sqrt{3}hr^2.$$ Multiply this by 6 to get the whole volume of the unit cell structure shown below.

I am struggling to find an expression for the height between consecutive planar hexagons in terms of the radius $r$, so that in the end I can take ratios. Doing this for a FCC or BCC structure  is fine since then we are dealing with a cube structure.

Many thanks (apologies for the size of the image, I can't see how to make it smaller)

.[image]

Comment: Does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_packing_factor#Hexagonal_close-packed) help, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: ah cool thanks ;) Yes, it is their $c$ that I am struggling to derive. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me there's a triangle between the two hexagon-levels (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres#mediaviewer/File:Hexagonal_close-packed_unit_cell.jpg)), so that, (together with assuming spheres of radius $a/2$ around each point) should give the answer after a bit of geometry, I think.

Comment: yes, that is what I assumed. For some reason, the geometry I can't get quite right.

Comment: The geometry is pretty straightforward.  You should get a close packed ratio of $\sqrt{2}\pi / 6$.

Comment: Hi Jon. Could you elaborate on the geometry? It is probably simple, but I have stared at it for some time and can't get it right. Thanks.